# Ember.js router and dynamic segments

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-old-router

I have been using [Ember's Router](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/router.js) (v1.0.pre) with single dynamic segments and really happy with it.
So much *magic*.

However, I'm struggeling with multiple dynamic segments:

- What should `serialize()`/`deserialize()` return?
- How should the `transitionTo()` call and the contex there look like?

Can somebody shed some light onto this?

Comment: I'm curious to understand what Ember world means with "dynamic segment".

Comment: @Abdull, "segment" - part of URL, "dynamic" - changes depending on current state of an application. Pretty straightforward, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `serialize` and `deserialize` should only be implemented when your context object has custom serialization *(i.e is not an ember-data model instance)*. So you should not have to implement these methods while using the full ember stack.
- `transitionTo` should be called from routes event handlers, and the context is passed as follow:

```js
showPost: function (router, event) {
  var post = event.context;
  router.transitionTo('posts.show', post);
}
```

Given the `showPost` event has been trigged by `action` helper like that:

```html
{{#each post in controller}}
  <a {{action showPost post}}>Show post {{post.title}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

More complex transitions can be achieved passing several context objects (for deeply nested routes):

```js
router.transitionTo('posts.member.comments.show', post, comment);
```

`post` & `comment` contexts will be passed to appropriated routes while routing will descend into nested routes.

---

**EDIT**

Without ember-data, it would look like:

```js
posts: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: 'posts',

  member: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/:post_id',

    show: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    }),

    comments: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: 'comments',

      show: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/:comment_id'
      })
    })
  })
})
```

And you would have two classes `App.Post` & `App.Comment`, with `find` class methods, and `id` instances property.

```js
App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null
});
App.Post.reopenClass({
  find: function (id) {
    // retrieve data, instanciate & return a new Post
  }
});

App.Comment = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null
});
App.Comment.reopenClass({
  find: function (id) {
    // retrieve data, instanciate & return a new Comment
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that's how far I got right now.  
I'm not using ember-data so I have to do the `find()` myself. 
In your example: how would `serialize()`/`deserialize()` look in the route _posts.member.comments.show_?

Comment: I've added samples for emberdata-less solution. Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Mike, thanks for the update, but in your example it's basically just 1 dynamic segment per route.  
My use case is: I have a dashboard with each widget being controlled by 1 controller. At the same time multiple widgets can be shown.  
I expect a url like: `'/charts/chart1/:id/chart2/:id'`  
So now I need to pass on multiple contexts to the route `charts` and have it setup each context of each controller. And here's were I'm getting into troubles.

Comment: Did you consider passing several ids (separated) rather than several segments concatenated. The url you give indicates three nested routes: charts > chart1 > chart2. It does not seems to match what you are looking for...